# OSX Scons building shared libraries: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, scons

Subtitle: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Building OpenCV and dlib with SCons on Mac OSX El Captain x86_64

I've been trying to make my app build in cross platform.

I have an SCons script that currently builds fine on windows, but it fails to build so in Mac.

I believe it is caused by some clashes with newer versions of XCode, because some of the previous versions of my code and scons worked nicely (before being refactored).

The following is the error message, and I believe it is quite common, but I seem to fail to find a way to remedy it.

In OpenCV2-highgui, cap_avfoundation.mm

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium", referenced from:
      CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in libOpencvHighgui.a(cap_avfoundation.o)
  "_AVFileTypeAppleM4V", referenced from:
      CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in libOpencvHighgui.a(cap_avfoundation.o)
  "_AVFileTypeMPEG4", referenced from:
      CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in libOpencvHighgui.a(cap_avfoundation.o)
  "_AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie", referenced from:
      CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in libOpencvHighgui.a(cap_avfoundation.o)
  "_AVMediaTypeVideo", referenced from:
      CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in libOpencvHighgui.a(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvCaptureFile::CvCaptureFile(char const*) in libOpencvHighgui.a(cap_avfoundation.o)
      CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in libOpencvHighgui.a(cap_avfoundation.o)
```

...
...
...

In OpenCV2-highgui, window_cocoa.mm

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSSlider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOpencvHighgui.a(window_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOpencvHighgui.a(window_cocoa.o)
      objc-class-ref in libOpencvHighgui.a(cap_avfoundation.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTextField", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOpencvHighgui.a(window_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSThread", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOpencvHighgui.a(window_cocoa.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURL", referenced from:
```

...
...
...

In addition to building OpenCV, same error occurred in dlib_18_14, source.cpp

```
  "_XAllocColor", referenced from:
      void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
  "_XAllocSizeHints", referenced from:
      dlib::base_window::set_size(int, int) in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
      dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
      dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
  "_XChangeProperty", referenced from:
      dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
  "_XCheckIfEvent", referenced from:
      dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::event_handler() in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
  "_XClearArea", referenced from:
      dlib::base_window::invalidate_rectangle(dlib::rectangle const&) in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
  "_XCloseDisplay", referenced from:
      nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::~vals_internal() in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
      dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::~event_handler_thread() in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
  "_XCloseIM", referenced from:
      dlib::gui_core_kernel_2_globals::event_handler_thread::~event_handler_thread() in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
  "_XConvertSelection", referenced from:
      dlib::get_from_clipboard(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >&) in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
  "_XCreateFontSet", referenced from:
      dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool) in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
      void nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::vals_internal::create<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, int, bool, bool, bool, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type, nativefont::font_renderer::font_renderer::rgb_type) in libThirdPartyDlib_18_14.a(source.o)
```

...
...
...

And the error is summed up as the following:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
scons: *** [out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/bin/libAPI3dfi_api_v1.dylib] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I cannot expose the entire source code nor the scons build scripts here, so please mind that.

This is the sample snippet of how my scons script looks like to build a shared library (building static libraries are having no problems, just the shared libs):

```
Import('env')

# Add third party libraries
lib_env = env.Clone()
module_lib_env = lib_env.Clone()
target_os = env.get('TARGET_OS')
target_arch = env.get('TARGET_ARCH')


######################################################################
# Runtime Dependencies
######################################################################
pthread_path = env.get('PTHREAD_PATH') + '/lib'
intraface_path = env.get('INTRAFACE_PATH') + '/lib'

######################################################################
# General flags
######################################################################
module_lib_env.AppendUnique(CPPPATH = ['inc', 'src'])

######################################################################
# Libraries
######################################################################
module_lib_env.AppendUnique(LIBPATH = [env.get('BUILD_DIR')+'/bin',env.get('BUILD_DIR')+'/lib', pthread_path, intraface_path])

if target_os == 'windows':
    module_lib_env.AppendUnique(LIBS = [
                                'libOpencvCore',
                                'libOpencvHighgui',
                                'libOpencvImgproc',
                                'libOpencvObjdetect',
                                'libOpencvFlann',
                                'libOpencvFeature2d',
                                'libOpencvVideo',
                                'libOpencvCalib3d',
                                'libOpencvMl',
                                'libFreeimage',
                                'libFreeimageOpenEXR',
                                'libFreeimageLibTIFF',
                                #'libFreeimageLibRawLite',
                                'libFreeimageLibPNG',
                                'libFreeimageLibOpenJPEG',
                                'libFreeimageLibJPEG',
                                'libFreeimageLibMNG',
                                'libFreeimageZLib',
                                'libThirdPartyDlib_18_14',
                                'pthread',
                                'IntraFaceDLL'])
else:
    module_lib_env.AppendUnique(LIBS = [
                                'libOpencvCore',
                                'libOpencvHighgui',
                                'libOpencvImgproc',
                                'libOpencvObjdetect',
                                'libOpencvFlann',
                                'libOpencvFeature2d',
                                'libOpencvVideo',
                                'libOpencvCalib3d',
                                'libOpencvMl',
                                'libFreeimage',
                                'libFreeimageOpenEXR',
                                'libFreeimageLibTIFF',
                                #'libFreeimageLibRawLite',
                                'libFreeimageLibPNG',
                                'libFreeimageLibOpenJPEG',
                                'libFreeimageLibJPEG',
                                'libFreeimageLibMNG',
                                'libFreeimageZLib',
                                'libThirdPartyDlib_18_14',
                                'pthread'
                                # ,'IntraFaceDLL'
                                ])


######################################################################
# Preprocessor flags
######################################################################
if not target_os == 'windows':
    #allow error to be concidered as warning
    module_lib_env.AppendUnique(CCFLAGS = ['-fpermissive'])
    #disable warning
    module_lib_env.AppendUnique(CCFLAGS = ['-Wno-sign-compare'])
    module_lib_env.AppendUnique(CCFLAGS = ['-Wno-write-strings'])
    module_lib_env.AppendUnique(CCFLAGS = ['-Wno-unused-variable'])
if target_os in ['darwin', 'ios']:
    module_lib_env.AppendUnique(CPPDEFINES = ['_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_VARIADICS'])

######################################################################
# Source files and Targets
######################################################################
lib_src = env.Glob('src/*.cpp')

######################################################################
# Targets
######################################################################
module_lib_env.InstallTargetShared('libOpenCV', lib_src )
```

Here is the [Full error log.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3fk9z14am5ye3l/error_log.txt?dl=0)

Here is how InstallTargetShared looks like:

```
def __install_shared(ienv, name, srcs):
    ienv.SharedLibrary(target = os.path.join(env.get('BUILD_DIR') +'/bin/', name), source = srcs)
    env.AppendUnique(TS = [name])

env.AddMethod(__install_shared, 'InstallTargetShared')
```

Any help or advices of what to do in this matter will be much appreciated!!

Comment: What is "InstallTargetShared" ?

Comment: @bdbaddog InstallTargetShared is a custom function for creating a shared library, which works fine on windows.

Comment: If you can't publish your sources here, the easiest would be to create a minimal working example (MWE) and use that instead to ask your question. Otherwise we won't be able to debug your problem properly...

Comment: @dirkbaechle I believe the problem I identified is compiling a third-party library OpenCV from source with SCons. I was able to build all the static libraries, but it outputs the above error when building shared libraries with OpenCV 2.4.6 and dlib, nothing with the source.

Comment: Can you post the source to InstallTargetShared?  Or as Dirk mentioned a minimal working example to demonstrate your problem.  Barring that we may not be able to resolve your issue.  How about a full log of your build?

Comment: @bdbaddog Done as you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your full build log, I think you need to link against several OSX frameworks to resolve your issues. I don't see any in your linking command line:

```
g++ -o out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/bin/libAPI3dfi_api_v1.dylib -ldl -lpthread -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -dynamiclib out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/NV3DFI_Api.os out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/NV3DFI_App_Manager.os out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/NV3DFI_App_Params.os out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/NV3DFI_App_Retry.os out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/NV3DFI_Event_Device_Heartbeat.os out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/NV3DFI_Event_Device_Init.os out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/NV3DFI_Event_Frame_Stats.os out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/NV3DFI_Event_Manager.os out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/NV3DFI_Event_Session_Assign.os out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/NV3DFI_Event_Session_End.os out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/NV3DFI_Event_Session_Start.os out/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/src/api/3dfi_api_v1/src/SHA1Hash.os -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -Ldeps/darwin/lib/x86_64 -Lout/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0 -L. -Lout/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/bin -Lbin -Lout/darwin/x86_64/release/1.0.0/lib -Llib -L/Users/tllewellynn/Desktop/dev/build_scons/runtime/darwin/xcode/x86_64/pthread/lib -L/Users/tllewellynn/Desktop/dev/build_scons/runtime/darwin/xcode/x86_64/intraface/lib -lSDK3dfi_detect -lSDK3dfi_algo -lSDK3dfi_au -lSDK3dfi_align -lSDK3dfi_proc -lSDK3dfi_cluster -lSDK3dfi_attr -lSDK3dfi_type -lOpencvCore -lOpencvHighgui -lOpencvImgproc -lOpencvObjdetect -lOpencvFlann -lOpencvFeature2d -lOpencvVideo -lOpencvCalib3d -lOpencvMl -lFreeimage -lFreeimageOpenEXR -lFreeimageLibTIFF -lFreeimageLibPNG -lFreeimageLibOpenJPEG -lFreeimageLibJPEG -lFreeimageLibMNG -lFreeimageZLib -lFrameworkNvaam_base -lFrameworkNvaam_filter -lFrameworkNvaam -lFrameworkProtobuf -lFrameworkLibbff -lFrameworkNvclassifier -lFrameworkNvexpression -lFrameworkTrimesh2 -lFrameworkPolyfit -lFrameworkGClasses -lFrameworkFlandmark -lFrameworkAlglib -lNetMsgpack -lNetJsoncpp -lNetTinyxml2 -lNetTinyxmlparam -lCnnEblearnTools -lCnnEblearnIdx -lCnnEblearn -lThirdPartyDlib_18_14 -lSystemTinycthread -lSystemTinythread -lSystemGlobal -lSystemDebug -lpthread -lTbb -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

Have you asked on any openCV forums or IRC channels?

Looks like you're missing several key frameworks from your link line.

Comment: I just had to link it to a few frameworks like CoreMedia and CoreVideo for the OpenCV linking issue.

Comment: Regarding the dlib, I posted an issue in it's Github repository, and figured out that I needed to link against X11.